# Cascades settings in JPA and foreign key violation in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cascade, entities

I have tow classes:

1. Parent
2. Child

In the database Child table has a column ParentId -> typical One (Parent) -> Many (Children) relation

Now I create two entities and they

```
public class Parent
{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="Parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Child> getChildern()
    {
      ...
    }
}

public class Child
{
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name="ParentId")
   public Parent getParent()
   { ... }
}
```

Now I have two scenarios:

1. Parent gets deleted -> what should happen?
2. Child gets deleted  -> what should happen?

Bonus questions:

1. Do I always need to create both parts of the key OneToMany and ManyToOne or can i just have ManyToOne and dont care in the parent where I have children?
2. What could cause a hibernate to give me a message foreign key constraint violation for a parent which has no children?

Comment: Probably you'll find all of the answers here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html#example-parentchild-cascades

Comment: Sorry it does not answer my questions :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all I'm surprised this code works at all. IMO `mappedBy="Parent"` should actually be `mappedBy="parent"` (note the lower-case 'p') because the parent property of the `Child` class is called `parent` and not `Parent`.

Second, I suggest you place the annotations on the properties rather than on the accessor methods. I find it makes the whole code

- more readable
- easier to maintain because [getters/setters can then be added behind the scenes by Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html)

Answers to your questions depend on what exactly you mean by "get deleted". I assume you mean "deleted through persistence manager".

BUT just in case you expect/want that a child is removed by the JPA provider if you do `parent.getChildren().remove(x)` then you need to set [`orphanRemoval = "true"`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/giqxy/index.html) on `OneToMany`.

**Question 1**

Parent and all children are deleted. That's the common case.

**Question 2**

Parent and all children are deleted. That's a rather odd use case. Usually cascade delete is only applied on the one-to-many relationship.

**Bonus 1**

> All relationships in Java and JPA are unidirectional, in that if a
> source object references a target object there is no guarantee that
> the target object also has a relationship to the source object.

from the excellent [Java Persistence wiki book](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany).

**Bonus 2**

Dunno. Is the `ConstraintViolationException` coming from the underlying data base? Or put differently, how does the DDL for the two tables look like? Was it generated by Hibernate?

Comment: Its is a sampled code made for simplicity reasons and u have not seen how my private fields are called. No query generated, hibernates breaks off, when I generate a delete query myself using id everything is fine. I actually want to prohibit any automated cascasion, which settings should i use then parent = persist, child = nothing?

Comment: Concerning weird not having a relationship on both sides, imagine that u have 5 entities of type parent and 100000 entities of type child, even with a lazy_loading it is a killer. I load children with the specific queries where filter a lot.

Comment: "want to prohibit any automated cascasion" - then don't define it. If you omit the `cascade` parameter [nothing happens](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#cascade()). However, I guess what you *really* want is that children are always automatically persisted, right? Then omit `cascade` in `ManyToOne` and set `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` in `OneToMany`.

Comment: That is what i did :)

Comment: Now what, all good? Really difficult to know if your problems are solved if you pack 4 questions into 1.